# How to fetch Maven dependencies from local m2 path(Second time) after downloaded from MVN or repo.spring sites?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working in Java spring boot with Maven. I want to download Maven dependencies from local m2 path for second time onwards. Don't want to download every time from main(mvnrepo, repo.spring.co...) sites.

First time I need to download from main repositories then second time onwards fetch from local m2 path.

Could you please help me with the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apa</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SampleTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
         <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>marklogic-xcc</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.mattryall.smarquotes</groupId>
  <artifactId>smarquotes</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/customfolder/smartquotes-1.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>SampleProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>SampleProject</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/customfolder/</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using a SNAPSHOT version instead of released versions? I strongly recommend to go with released version which are available in Maven Central (2.5.4 and 2.6.0-M2) https://spring.io/blog/2021/08/19/spring-boot-2-6-0-m2-is-now-available. Furthermore using system scope dependencies is long deprecated. I strongly discourage that.. Also remove the configuration for maven-war-plugin but define the version at least....

Comment: @khmarbaise - Thank you for your recommendation. Definitely I will change the POM in my project. Could you please help me on my requirement of second time fetch from local m2 path.

Comment: @KrishnakumarSubbaiyan If you are not using SNAPSHOTS, then Maven will not redownload the artifacts. So just do what khmarbaise said.